# Is it possible to sort files on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud

Also, is it possible to set a default sort order for a bucket on Amazon S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For viewing, or for some additional processing?

If you want to sort the files for viewing on a Windows desktop, an inexpensive option is to install [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/S3_Client.html) and map a drive to Amazon S3.  You can do a column sort by date, file type, name, etc.